# How do I run multiple npm scripts at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

Editor: vsCode, shell: bash, OS: windows.

I tried & operator, but only start the server.

```
   "start": "npm run server & npm run client"
```

and I add start at the beginning, it works perfectly but gives me a new window.

```
   "start": "start npm run server & npm run client"
```

Is there any other way to run it parallel without installing the npm module or jump another window?

Comment: use `&&` instead of `&`

Comment: Why don't you want to use [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) ?

Comment: or use pre and post [scrpit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#npm-start)